# Schedule Multiple Emails Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, email, scheduler

I am using SMTPlib package to create multiple emails in one application and the code works fine to send email. But, I want to be able to schedule each email to be sent at different day/time.

For instance, one at 9AM Monday and another at 12 Noon Wed.

I looked at some slightly different questions and answers on SO, where the recommendation is use of Crontab. However, Crontab is only helpful to schedule the entire application not individual parts of the application.

Sched package is also available, but I am not familiar with it and hence not sure, if I can efficiently use this for my use case.

Appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create separate python file/process responsible only for sending emails. You can run it when you need to queue/send emails and you might just kill it afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I can. But, considering large number of emails, it would be very hard to maintain them in place over time. I am looking for a simpler approach. Thanks anyways!